# PostgreSQL cross server query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-server

Is there a way that I might query a database located on "Server 2" and get my data in "Server 1" ? That is return a set of records from a remote server to my local one.

PS: Not cross database query on same server because I know how to do that with dblink.

**Update:** great ty.

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html works like a charm. My bust was that I didn't see it on the dblink documentation on postgresql website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to perform cross-database queries with postgres?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324/possible-to-perform-cross-database-queries-with-postgres)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently dblink can be used to query other servers - [Using DbLink to access other PostreSQL Databases and Servers](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html)

Answer (score 15):

this is old - these days one would use the postgres_fdw module instead: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: I suggest the correct answer be changed to this - this is more relevant and correct for today.