# What's the potential risk if we join two tables located in a separated databases

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.
I have two separated databases which have a tables I need to **join**. As known I can use `dblink` query to access to the remote database.

```
select * 
from 
    customer  
    INNER JOIN  
    dblink('host=192.168.3.9 dbname=db2 user=postgres password=postgres', '
        SELECT
            id
        FROM campaign_customer
        ') AS table2 (
            int id
            date_added char(50)
        ) ON customer.cust_id = table2.id
```

It looks a bit strange. Does such a solution cause a potential (I mean `join` via `dblink`) risk? If yes, can you explain what exact is that risk? I would like to look at any other possible solution.

I'm especially interested in the performance of such query and how it can affect to a transaction to a different database?

Comment: Please add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry. Fixed.

Comment: What kinds of risk are you worried about? Security? Slow Queries? Unreliable Queries? Excess resource usage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678862/joining-results-from-two-separate-databases expands on KIM's answer and explains why a fdw will typically have better performance than dblink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd ratter say `FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER` is better way which can avoid connection string exposure.