# Is it possible to run a join between two different AWS Redshift Databases in the same cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

just wondering if this is possible? I see some older links stating this is not possible from 2015 or so but wondering if it is now and if there is any available documentation that states yay/nay. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is **not possible** to queries across or JOIN logical databases created via the [CREATE DATABASE command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_DATABASE.html).

This is the same for PostgreSQL, on which Amazon Redshift was based. See: [Joining Results from Two Separate Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4678939/174777)

While PostgreSQL has the `dlink` module that can join separate databases (on the same cluster or otherwise), this capability is **not** available for Amazon Redshift.