# How to select tables from different databases in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to get select data from 2 different tables that they are in 2 different databases. Using SQL Server I would do `SELECT * FROM database.schema.table`,
but I tried that and it didn't work using Amazon Redshift.

Does anyone knows how to achieve that?

Comment: I don't think there is a way, when you connect to Redshift you pads database name in connection string, which means you are bound to access data only from that database in that Redshift cluster.

Comment: FYI.. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=143821

Comment: See: [Is it possible to run a join between two different AWS Redshift Databases in the same cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50959302/174777)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift does not support cross db references. i.e : you can't call anything outside of the current database.
Two solutions here :

1. move to another DWH that supports cross db references : snowflake or BQ mainly
2. copy data to s3 and then load it to your target db

Comment: No longer true as of late 2020.  Adding new answer.

Answer (score 3):

As of late 2020, this is possible via "cross-database queries".  For more information, see the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cross-database-overview.html).