# How I can connect multiple Postgres Database in a single SQL query?

Tags: postgresql, metabase

**This is Metabase Related Question. I know how to cross join in PostgreSQL.**

I have multiple staging databases to store raw data in postgreSQL. All databases are in same host.

Now I want to join multiple databases for analysis in Metabase. I saw before create a raw query first I need to select database.

Is there any way around for this ?

Comment: this could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678862/joining-results-from-two-separate-databases

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why you marked this as duplicate ? I asked it for Metabase perspective. Did you know how to connect it through Metabase ?

Comment: The approach to access multiple databases in a single query is independent of the tool you are using