# Is it possible to use multiple databases within same query using pg-promise?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I have two related tables T1 and T2 in different databases D1 and D2. I need to do an inner join between two tables.

From here: [Joining Results from Two Separate Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678862/joining-results-from-two-separate-databases) it is clear that separate queries should be made to two databases and results to be consolidated on client side OR use dblink / [postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).

However, I see this issue: [Multiple Databases #1](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/1)
 and the use of `$dc` parameter here: [pg-promise/Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html).

I believe issue: [Multiple Databases #1](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/1)
 just facilitates allowing connecting to multiple databases within the same codebase.

The description of `$dc` parameter states:

> This is mainly to facilitate the use of multiple databases which may need separate protocol extensions, or different implementations within a single task

However, I did not find any examples.

Is the `$dc` paramter just a database context object that can be accessed, or would it allow to do an inner join between two different databases?

Is there a way to do utilise two database connections but do a join across databases in without having to do it on client-side using `pg-promise`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the $dc paramter just a database context object that can be accessed, or would it allow to do an inner join between two different databases?

It is the former.

> Is there a way to do utilise two database connections but do a join across databases in without having to do it on client-side using pg-promise?

No. Each [Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) object represents only a single connection to A database.

[Database Context](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#$dc) is there to allow re-use of tasks, transactions and protocol extensions across multiple [Database](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html) objects, by relying on its value.