# Union from 2 different data sources (same server )

Tags: sql, postgresql, tableau-api, union-all

How do I union 2 different data sources? not join- I want to union data !

1 tablename - from base1

2 tablename - from base2

base1 and base2 from same server (postgrsql)

ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "base2.public.requete_ca"
LINE 1: select * from     base2.public.requete_ca

Comment: Are the two tables in different databases or just different schemas?  It looks like they might be in different databases, which means you'll need to use dblink or the postgres_fdw (preferred).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this natively in Tableau Desktop using the visual drag-and-drop data source screen.  You can do this in Tableau Prep if you have a license.

The only way to do this in Tableau Desktop is to use Custom Sql.  You can use an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678862/joining-results-from-two-separate-databases).