# Postgresql how to insert (or update) a local database (or table) with entries (or a query) from a remote database?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database called `tables` with 2 tables which looks like this

`readingtable`

```
date         reading1 reading2 reading3 source
2021-01-01   xx       xx       xx       x1
2021-01-01   xx       xx       xx       x2
2021-01-01   xx       xx       xx       x3
...
2021-01-01   xx       xx       xx       x150
2021-01-02   xx       xx       xx       x1
2021-01-02   xx       xx       xx       x2
....
2021-06-29   xx       xx       xx       x150
```

`booltable`

```
date         bool1    bool2    bool3    source
2021-01-01   xx       xx       xx       x1
2021-01-01   xx       xx       xx       x2
2021-01-01   xx       xx       xx       x3
...
2021-01-01   xx       xx       xx       x150
2021-01-02   xx       xx       xx       x1
2021-01-02   xx       xx       xx       x2
....
2021-06-29   xx       xx       xx       x150
```

I have 150 sources which save reading to my postgresql server which are saved to 2 tables.

So example, today I would get the following data appended to the `readingtable` table

```
date         reading1 reading2 reading3 source
2021-06-30   xx       xx       xx       x1
2021-06-30   xx       xx       xx       x2
2021-06-30   xx       xx       xx       x3
...
2021-06-30   xx       xx       xx       x150
```

I have another backup postgresql server in mylaptop where I save the readings everyday.

But to do that, what I do is first `delete from booltable;` and `delete from readingtable;`.

Then I do `pg_dump -h $remoteip -p $remoteport -U $remoteuser -C tables  | psql -h localhost -d tables -U $localuser`

This copies every entry in the database.

Is there a way for my local database to just compare with the remote database and only update the entries which are missing (the latest date's 150 entries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to know about [foreign data wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers). This feature allows communication from one PostgreSQL database server to another database server. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36904631/9705687) links to postgres_fdw, which allows comms from PostgreSQL to PostgreSQL.

Install the extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
```

Create a server. This only works if your server is accepting connections:

```
CREATE SERVER foreign_server
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS (host '192.83.123.89', port '5432', dbname 'foreign_db');
```

Create foreign table(s):

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_readingtable (
    date date,
    reading1 text,
    reading2 text,
    reading3 text,
    source   text)
    SERVER foreign_server
    OPTIONS (schema_name 'some_schema', table_name 'readingtable');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_booltable (
    date   date,
    bool1  boolean,
    bool2  boolean,
    bool3  boolean,
    source text)
    SERVER foreign_server
    OPTIONS (schema_name 'some_schema', table_name 'booltable');
```

With the foreign tables all set up, now it becomes a question of how to getting the data in the right place with either `SELECT INTO` or `INSERT` statements