# How to write a join query with "two database" in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

How to write a join query with two database in cakephp. Here is my code and I want to connect two db connection but I have a single Db Connection.

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Controller\AppController;
    use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
    use src\Model\Table\classScheduleDbConnTable;

    class TimeTableController extends AppController {
        public function index() {
            $jpDB = ConnectionManager::get('default');
            $ClsDB = ConnectionManager::get('test');
            $result = $ClsDB->execute('SELECT * FROM t_class_schedule')->fetchAll('assoc');
            $data=array();
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key]['id'] = $value['id'];
                $dates = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($value['classDate']));
                $data[$key]['fromTime'] = $value['fromTime'];
                $data[$key]['toTime'] = $value['toTime'];
                $data[$key]['keyWord'] = $value['keyWord'];
                $data[$key]['classDate'] = $dates;
            }
            $this->set('datas',$data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't even use the CakePHP query builder, so that this seems more like a question related to whatever DBMS you are using, ie a plain SQL problem? **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033558/how-to-use-different-datasources-in-a-query-using-cakephp3**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can just "connect" two ConnectionManagers in this way.

You probably have two options:

**Option A** - Specify the database name statically as part of the Table's initialization per the example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034850/2403513):

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('databaseName.tableName');
    // ...
}
```

**Option B** - Specify an alternative connection & Lazy Load

You can specify an [alternative connection names](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#configuring-connections) for a specific Model at the Table level:

```
class ClassSchedule extends Table
{
    public static function defaultConnectionName() {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Note that this can't be used in a join on other Tables using the `default` connection. You'll instead have to "lazy load" associated data manually. As a general example (I don't know what your associations are, just a random example):

```
$student->class_schedules = TableRegistry::get('ClassSchedules')->find()
    ->where(['student_id'=>$student-id])
    ->toArray();
```