# CakePHP 3 is saying a table doesn't exist in another database when using an ORM query

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have an application in CakePHP 3.5.13 which uses four different databases.

In my `config/app.php` I have configured two of these as follows:

```
'Datasources' => [ 
    'default' => [ 'database' => 'sdb5_hub_subdb', ... ],
    'db_orgs' => [ 'database' => 'dev_hub_subdb_orgs', ... ]
];
```

So this means there are 2 databases with the names `sdb5_hub_subdb` and `dev_hub_subdb_orgs`.

I'm attempting to do a query which does a join on a table in each database.

I have my `Table` entities configured as follows:

```
// src/Model/Table/TblListsSubstancesCommentsTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->belongsTo('Substances', [
        'foreignKey' => 'substance_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}

public static function defaultConnectionName()
{
    return 'db_orgs';
}


// src/Model/Table/SubstancesTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->belongsTo('TblListsSubstancesComments', [
        'foreignKey' => 'substance_id'
    ]);
}
```

When I attempt to do the following with the ORM:

```
$query = $Substances->find()->select(['id' => 'Substances.id'])->distinct();

if ($this->request->getData('org_information')) {
    $org_information = $this->request->getData('org_information');
    $query = $query->matching('TblListsSubstancesComments', function ($q) use ($org_information) {
    return $q->where(['TblListsSubstancesComments.comment LIKE' => '%'.$org_information.'%' ]);
     });
 }
```

It's producing an SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sdb5_hub_subdb.tbl_lists_substances_comments' doesn't exist

I don't understand this because the table definitely exists. Furthermore my `TblListsSubstancesCommentsTable.php` has `defaultConnectionName()` in it to specify that it should use the `db_orgs` connection. So I assume it must know to go to the second database to load that table? It's like it's looking in the default database and not finding it, but I don't know why, because the Table entity is telling it where it needs to look.

Comment: It's still not supported: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033558/how-to-use-different-datasources-in-a-query-using-cakephp3**. Connection configuration is only used for querying on the specific table, not for joining.

Comment: That's a pretty serious limitation. People do segment data into different databases! You can even bake things on different datasources which probably adds to the confusion/strangeness of that situation too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use different datasources in a Query using cakephp3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033558/how-to-use-different-datasources-in-a-query-using-cakephp3)