# CakePHP 3 - Cross database ORM query with hierarchical data not possible even when relationships are defined

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP 3.7. I have an application which stores a hierarchical list of filters. A user can subscribe/un-subscribe from them.

2 separate databases - both of which are on the same server - are used to store this data. Both are defined in `config/app.php`:

```
'Datasources' => [
    // Hierarchical filters list (consists of 3 tables) stored in this DB
    'default' => [
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'database' => 'db1_name',
        // ...
    ],
    // Filters a user has subscribed to (in 1 table) stored in this DB
    'subscriptions' => [
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'database' => 'db2_name',
        // ...
    ],
]
```

I'm wanting to do a query which does a `JOIN` using tables from both databases so have used the information here [How to use different datasources in a Query using cakephp3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033558/how-to-use-different-datasources-in-a-query-using-cakephp3)

The hierarchical list of filters uses 3 tables (in the `default` DB). hierarchy is as follows:

- `regulations`

  - `groups`

    - `filters`

I've baked the appropriate Table classes and done what's described on the linked answer to use the appropriate connection. So I have this:

```
 // Model/Table/RegulationsTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable(ConnectionManager::get('default')->config()['database'] . '.regulations');

    $this->hasMany('Groups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'regulation_id'
    ]);
}

// Model/Table/GroupsTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable(ConnectionManager::get('default')->config()['database'] . '.groups');

    $this->belongsTo('Regulations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'regulation_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Filters', [
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
    ]);
}

// Model/Table/FiltersTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable(ConnectionManager::get('default')->config()['database'] . '.filters');

    $this->belongsTo('Groups', [
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('TblRegulatoryAlerts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'f_id',
    ]);
}
```

The table which stores the `filters.id` which the user is subscribed to is in the second database (see `subscriptions` key in `config/app.php` posted earlier). So again this has been done in the appropriate Table class:

```
// Model/Table/TblRegulatoryAlertsTable.php
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable(ConnectionManager::get('subscriptions')->config()['database'] . '.tbl_regulatory_alerts');

    $this->belongsTo('Filters', [
        'foreignKey' => 'f_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

**The problem I'm having** is doing a query through the ORM. I want to find all of the rows that exist for a given user in `TblRegulatoryAlertsTable` and then do a `JOIN` to the other database to get the `Regulations.*` fields. Of course `Regulations` is at the top of the hierarchy and we're starting with records that correspond to `Filters`, so it needs to work back up the hierarchy (`filters` ---> `groups` ---> `regulations`).

`TblRegulatoryAlertsTable.f_id` corresponds to `Filters.id` (if there is a row it means the user has subscribed to that filter) and there is a `TblRegulatoryAlertsTable.u_id` to represent the user ID.

The Table classes appear to have these relationships defined correctly, unless I'm mistaken?

So I've taken a look at [Eager Loading Associations Via Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain) from the Cake docs.

But when I do this:

```
// Model/Table/RegulationsTable.php
public function getUserSubscriptionRegions($u_id = null)
{
    $data = $this->find()->select(['Regulations.id', 'Regulations.label'])->distinct(['Regulations.id', 'Regulations.label'])
            ->contain([
        'Groups' => ['Filters', 'TblRegulatoryAlerts']])
            ->enableHydration(false)
            ->toArray();
    return $data;
}
```

It says

> The TblRegulatoryAlerts association is not defined on Groups.

Of course it isn't. Because it has to go through the hierarchy of `Filters` to get the `Groups` followed by the `Regulations`.

There's also the issue of how/where to pass in `u_id`? However that's not even going to be possible unless the `JOIN` will work.

So **the question is** - I'm not sure how to define this via the ORM. How can I write this in the ORM syntax?

Ironically I've written it as plain SQL query using https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#executing-queries and it works without any issue. The equivalent SQL is:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT db1_name.regulations.id, db1_name.regulations.label 
FROM
  db1_name.groups
JOIN db1_name.regulations
  ON db1_name.groups.regulation_id = db1_name.regulations.id 
JOIN db1_name.filters
  ON db1_name.filters.group_id = db1_name.groups.id 
JOIN db2_name.tbl_regulatory_alerts 
  ON db2_name.tbl_regulatory_alerts.f_id = dev_hub_subdb.filters.id 
WHERE db2_name.tbl_regulatory_alerts.u_id = 1234
```

It would be nice to be able to use the ORM to write queries like this though. Or is it just one of those things that's too complex for the ORM and it's better to keep it as plain SQL?

*For information:*

1. The plain SQL queries above do not actually have `db1_name` etc hardcoded into them. If you are doing it like that then it's possible to use `ConnectionManager::get('default')->config()['database'];` to get the DB name dynamically. This was just to illustrate the SQL used.
2. The fact it's using 2 separate database isn't something that can be changed. It's a legacy system I'm working with and the DB's need to remain as-is. Clearly doing a cross database join is possible because the plain SQL executes without any issue.

Comment: You contain configuration isn't properly nested. `'Groups' => ['Filters' => ['TblRegulatoryAlerts']]` or `Groups.Filters.TblRegulatoryAlerts`

Comment: It errors: The `tblRegulatoryAlertsDb1Name.filters` association is not defined on `TblRegulatoryAlerts`. I've deleted files in `tmp/cache/models/*`

Comment: That looks like a database/table name used as association name (these example database/table names are kinda confusing, it's usually better to use your real names), from the shown code I couldn't tell where that might happen. Inspect the stack trace to figure where this happens / from where it is triggered.