# How to query from one database to another

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using postgres I have wrote a query to list the tables inside a database

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND table_schema NOT IN
('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

Query returns results from the wrong database. It automatically selects the first database from the list of databases in postgres.

How do I specify the database to query? 'j220190_data' being the database to query

I've tried things like:

```
    SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE Databases = 'j220190_data'
AND table_schema NOT IN
('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');

SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND
WHERE Databases = 'j220190_data'
AND table_schema NOT IN
('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

Comment: "Works fine. but it doesnt work"...

Comment: "*How do I specify the database to query*" - you can't you need to first _connect_ to the other database. Postgres does not support cross-database queries

Comment: "*It automatically selects the first database from the list of databases in postgres*" - that's wrong. That query returns the information of the database you are currently connected to.

Comment: I tried connecting to the database first using \connect 'j220190_data' but this didnt work either

Comment: How do I connect to a database of my choosing please?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324/possible-to-perform-cross-database-queries-with-postgres

Comment: How you connect to a different database depends on the SQL client you are using.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to postgres select database; 
for example:

```
psql mydb
```

and after you post the select, because when you try whit this select, postgres checks on default database.

Comment: @John: [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference-client.html) is a **command line** program, not a SQL statement.

Comment: when u connect at postgres db, you can connect at db that you want, you try with psql j220190_data, if your database is this. You connect from shell obviously

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can query another database using [`dblink()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html).

Create extension `CREATE EXTENSION dblink;`

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM dblink('dbname=DB1 port=5432   
            host=localhost user=usr password=123', 'SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = ''BASE TABLE'' 
AND table_schema NOT IN(''pg_catalog'', ''information_schema'');') 
AS tbl(table_name varchar(30));
```