# How to do insert and select in single query in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.5

Insert into order
Select * from order
Where id =1

Can anyone pls tell me , In postgresql query
If we have same name of tables but from different databases. Like in insert operation, the  order table is belongs to Product1 database and in select operation order table belongs to product2 database.

Comment: Perhaps check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448/7182460

Comment: I have created foreign data wrapper tables in product1 database for product2 table "order" with the name change like product2_order. So when i am access this table from product1 database , this table is accessing. But from vb.net application. I am getting error like product2_order is not a table. Can anyone tell me why it is showing error.