# How can I UNION two tables in different PostgeSQL databases?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm running PostgreSQL 11.8 in a Docker container. I have two databases: `website_db` and `testdb`.

`website_db` has a products table with `id`, `product_name`, `colour`, `product_size` columns

`testdb` has a table called users with `id`, `username`, `password`

I'm using `website_db` and I want to `UNION` columns from the users table in the `testdb` database. I can get this to work in MySQL but am struggling with Postgres. Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = 'doesntexist' OR 1=1 UNION SELECT null,username,password,null FROM testdb.users;
```

I get this error back:

```
ERROR:  relation "testdb.users" does not exist
LINE 1: ...1=1 UNION SELECT null,username,password,null FROM testdb.use...
```

Does anyone know what I have to do to fix my query?

Comment: Well does this database/table actually exist?

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324/possible-to-perform-cross-database-queries-with-postgresql

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes the db/table exists. Here's screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/hK9nbHt

Comment: Echoing shawnt00's answer. postgres_fdw is the way to go. You can't simply query another database without setting that up.

Comment: "*I can get this to work in MySQL*" - what MySQL calls a "database" is in reality a schema. So you should simply use separate schemas in Postgres, not separate databases - then you don't have those problems any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html):

```
create database first;
create database second;
\c first;

create table products
(
    id serial not null
        constraint products_pk
            primary key,
    product_name varchar(50) not null
);


INSERT INTO public.products (id, product_name) VALUES (1, 'first_db');

\c second;

create table products
(
    id serial not null
        constraint products_pk
            primary key,
    product_name varchar(50) not null
);


INSERT INTO public.products (id, product_name) VALUES (1, 'sec_db');

-- dblink -- executes a query in a remote database 
create extension dblink;

-- change queries and creds
SELECT id, product_name FROM products
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=first user=root password=root', 'SELECT id, product_name FROM products') AS tb2(id int, product_name text);
```